# Quanto gasta uma requisição HTTP?

Tags: http, redes

**Cliente**

envia um post **sem corpo** para uma API qualquer

```
post('api.dominio.com')
```

**Servidor**

retorna somente o código de status 204

```
return res.status(204)
```

Supondo que a situação acima aconteça, o cliente faz uma requisição sem enviar nada (praticamente um GET), e o servidor sabendo que quando aquele endpoit for requisitado, deve fazer alguma coisa e no final só responder 204, sem retornar mais nada. Nessa requisição, o usuário gastou dados?

não sei se estou sendo claro, mas a minha dúvida é mais sobre o protocolo HTTP, qual o custo minimo dele? um Status Code consome dados?

Comment: Consumir sim, mesmo que bem pouco. Porém não deixou de haver uma comunicação com o servidor, passar pelos roteadores até ele, processamento de request, envio da resposta... Sempre há consumo. Agora, se foi algo que afete o desempenho de aplicações, aí só se a banda e processamento do servidor for baixo e as requisições serem feitas aos milhares ao mesmo tempo. Mesmo tempo, digo, dentro de, digamos, 10 milésimos de segundo, por exemplo... Gostaria de ver um teste que possa captar quantos bytes consome na comunicação, por curiosidade também...

Comment: @RodrigoTognin Vai depender da quantidade de headers da requisição/resposta.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin respondi a pergunta com um exemplo e uma forma de medição aproximada da requisição

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim o usuário gastou dados, você pode simular este comportamento fazendo seu próprio experimento conforme demonstro abaixo:

Para isso utilizei o [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) e o [Webhook.site](https://webhook.site/#!/86ad55b1-e790-46ba-a2e6-ac753078e172/0754a016-5f1e-4c0e-96fc-a52143750fe3/1):

Realizando um POST para a URL do Webhook gerado, você pode acompanhar sua requisição chegando ao site e devolvendo ao Postman o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode ver na imagem que mesmo sem passar nenhum corpo na requisição, eu enviei aproximadamente **307 bytes em headers** para o Webhook.site, e em sua resposta ele me devolveu aproximadamente **380 bytes também em headers**, sem nenhum conteúdo no body.

Abaixo você pode ver todas as informações enviadas e recebidas nos headers dessa requisição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo sem body, existe uma variação nos headers. Tudo depende da quantidade de informação passada e devolvida, cada servidor/aplicação devolve uma quantidade X de dados. A melhor forma seria de fato medir realizando uma requisição para a API.